# Unable to rebuild a working OWL ontology using Jena OntModel API

Tags: java, sparql, jena, owl

I am evaluating the Jena query capabilities associated with the [Model API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) and I am facing an issue. First, I test queries on restrictions. Actually, Jena is one of the available APIs which allow querying inferred models. Furthermore, I need to split the schema from the data so, using Protégé, I created two separate RDF files with two distinct namespaces.

In the first namespace, `http://www.test.com/schema#`, for the schema, there is one class: `Woman`; one object property: `hasSpouse`; and one equivalent class on a restriction on `hasSpouse : Husband`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.test.com/schema#"
     xml:base="http://www.test.com/schema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <!--<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.test.com/schema"/>-->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.test.com/schema#hasSpouse">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.test.com/schema#Woman"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.test.com/schema#Husband">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.test.com/schema#hasSpouse"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.test.com/schema#Woman"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.test.com/schema#Woman"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

In the second namespace, `http://www.test.com/data#`, there are two individuals: `john` and `janette`. `janette` is a `Woman` and `john`'s spouse is `janette`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY schema "http://www.test.com/schema#">
]>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.test.com/data#"
     xml:base="http://www.test.com/data#"
     xmlns:schema="http://www.test.com/schema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.test.com/data#janette">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.test.com/schema#Woman"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.test.com/data#john">
        <schema:hasSpouse rdf:resource="http://www.test.com/data#janette"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

My test query is finding every `husband` in the data, and I expect to get `john`. Here is the query:

```
   PREFIX schema: <http://www.test.com/schema#>
   select ?subject where {?subject a schema:Husband}
```

Everything works well using the code below

```java
    System.out.println("QUERY ON LOADED RESTRICTION");
    String path = "....";

    Model schema = FileManager.get().loadModel("file:"+path+"married_schema_ns.xml");
    schema.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
    Model data = FileManager.get().loadModel("file:"+path+"married_data_ns.xml");
    data.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");   

    Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
    reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(schema);
    InfModel inf_model = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, data);    

    String query_string = "PREFIX schema: <http://www.test.com/schema#>\r\n";
    query_string += "select ?subject where {?subject a schema:Husband}";

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(query_string);      
    query.serialize(new IndentedWriter(System.out));
    QueryExecution execution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model);

    ResultSet results = execution.execSelect();
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution solution = results.nextSolution();
        RDFNode node = solution.get("subject");
        System.out.println("subject="+node);
    } 

    System.out.println("END ....");
```

The system replies `subject=http://www.test.com/data#john` as expected.  I tried to build exactly the same `Model` from scratch, but afterward the query doesn't work anymore.

```java
    System.out.println("QUERY ON BUILT RESTRICTION");
    OntModel ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    String ns_ontology="http://www.test.com/schema#";
    String pr_ontology = "schema";
    ontology.setNsPrefix("", ns_ontology);

    ObjectProperty has_spouse = ontology.createObjectProperty(ns_ontology+"hasSpouse");   
    OntClass woman = ontology.createClass(ns_ontology+"Woman");
    has_spouse.setRange(woman);

    OntClass husband = ontology.createClass(ns_ontology+"Husband");       
    SomeValuesFromRestriction restriction = ontology.createSomeValuesFromRestriction(null, has_spouse, woman);
    husband.addEquivalentClass(restriction);

    String ns_facts = "http://www.test.com/data#";
    String pr_facts = "data";

    OntModel facts = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    facts.setNsPrefix("", ns_facts);
    facts.setNsPrefix(pr_ontology, ns_ontology);
    Resource r = facts.getResource("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual");
    Individual john = facts.createIndividual(ns_facts+"john",r);        
    Individual janette = facts.createIndividual(ns_facts+"janette",r);
    janette.addProperty(RDF.type, woman);
    john.addProperty(has_spouse, janette);              

    Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
    reasoner.bindSchema(ontology);
    Model inf_model = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, facts);

    String query_string = "PREFIX schema: <"+ns_ontology+">\r\n";
    query_string += "select ?subject where {?subject a schema:Husband}";

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(query_string);      
    query.serialize(new IndentedWriter(System.out));
    QueryExecution execution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model);

    ResultSet results = execution.execSelect();
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution solution = results.nextSolution();
        RDFNode node = solution.get("subject");
        System.out.println("subject="+node);
    } 
    System.out.println("END ...");
```

I don't understand the reason why. The RDF/XML-ABBREV serialization of the two versions match perfectly.

**Moreover, when I load the built schema/data serialization in the first version the query works again**.

If someone could help me to understand this point!

Comment: Is this the actual code you're running? Your query execution `QueryExecution execution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model);` references `model`, but I don't see any variable `model`.  (This is in both the first and second code blocks.)

Comment: actually I originaly create a function for the query execution and i copy paste the body for readibility. i Forgot to update variable name sorry!

Comment: Try to writeAll the model in the second solution. Do the axioms reported match the axioms in the protege ontology? If you want to programatically find differences, you could create two HashSet<Statement> objects, and, using those objects, compare the statements in the models.

Comment: I found! I forget to reassign the variable reasoner after the call his bindSchema method `reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(schema)`. Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: @jeanmi You should add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to reassign the variable reasoner after the call his `bindSchema` method `reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(schema)`.